# GridView Divider

Tags: gridview, flutter, divider

How can I create a divider like that for GridView. You see it has dashed lines and a circle in the middle. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you mean how to create dashed lines that's not available as of now and there is an open issue for that

- [Support for dashed line #4858](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4858)

how ever you can try to use this [dash_path.dart](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_path_drawing/blob/master/lib/src/dash_path.dart) implementation and you can also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164276/4511702) for more details about the issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raouf. Let's eliminate the dash part for now.How do you place a normal divider between grid items? I just put vertical(end of item) and horizontal dividers(bottom of item) as part of the grid item and put some if checks for last column to not show vertical one.  Is there a better way to do it?